# NSDictionary > JSON String using SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, swifty-json

This is what I'm doing to convert it. The log returns `nil`

```
let keys = ["firstName", "lastName", "age","carNumber", "licenseNumber", "email","password", "msgType"]
let objects = ["Pencil", "Eraser", "2332","534543", "543543", "Notebook","Pencil", "ADD_DRIVER"]
self.dictionary = NSDictionary(objects: objects, forKeys: keys)

var data = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
data.append(self.dictionary as! Dictionary<String, String>);
var jsonObj = JSON(data)

print("JSON Object")
print(jsonObj.stringValue)
```

Comment: You should add a note about what you were expecting the output to be... What happens if you make data of type Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?

Comment: I expect the output to be a valid JSON string, which I can post to the server.

Answer (score 7):

To make a JSON string with SwiftyJSON, use `rawString(encoding: UInt = default, options opt: NSJSONWritingOptions = default)`. This way the string will not contain invalid characters like new lines.

Example for a dictionary:

```
let keys = ["firstName", "lastName", "age","carNumber", "licenseNumber", "email","password", "msgType"]
let objects = ["Pencil", "Eraser", "2332","534543", "543543", "Notebook","Pencil", "ADD_DRIVER"]
let dict = NSDictionary(objects: objects, forKeys: keys)
let jsonObj = JSON(dict)
if let stringJSON = jsonObj.rawString(NSUTF8StringEncoding, options: []) {
    print(stringJSON)
}
```

Result:

> {"lastName":"Eraser","password":"Pencil","age":"2332","firstName":"Pencil","licenseNumber":"543543","email":"Notebook","carNumber":"534543","msgType":"ADD_DRIVER"}

If like in your snippet you want it in an array before encoding to JSON string, then just embed it in an array like this:

```
let keys = ["firstName", "lastName", "age","carNumber", "licenseNumber", "email","password", "msgType"]
let objects = ["Pencil", "Eraser", "2332","534543", "543543", "Notebook","Pencil", "ADD_DRIVER"]
let dict = NSDictionary(objects: objects, forKeys: keys)
let jsonObj = JSON([dict])
if let stringJSON = jsonObj.rawString(NSUTF8StringEncoding, options: []) {
    print(stringJSON)
}
```

Result:

> [{"msgType":"ADD_DRIVER","password":"Pencil","firstName":"Pencil","age":"2332","email":"Notebook","carNumber":"534543","licenseNumber":"543543","lastName":"Eraser"}]

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it for submission to RESTful API:

```
let submitJson: JSON =  ["user": username, "pass": password]
self.body = submitJson.rawString()!
```

print(self.body) returns:

{
  "pass" : "xxx",
  "user" : "xxx"
}